# Block Level Backup Engine Service freeze server for minutes

Tags: windows-server-2008

Win SBS2011. The Block Level Backup Engine Service starts every hour automatically and for minutes the server is not accessable . The network maps are disconnecting and every file operations stop. After minutes everything goes back to normal. Anyone has solution for this problem ?

Thanks﻿

Comment: Why don't you schedule your backups for after work hours?

Comment: How are your backups configured?  Is it trying to connect to an unreachable drive?  Is one of your hard drives slowly failing (check with SMART)?  What's in the event log?

Comment: My backup runs at 23:00. This serivce starts by default. I don't know what its function but it stops the network. Event log something like this :The Block Level Backup Engine Service service entered the running state.
The Volume Shadow Copy service entered the running state.
The Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider service entered the running state.
The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service service entered the running state.
The Group Policy settings for the computer were processed successfully. The Volume Shadow Copy service entered the stopped state.

Comment: Same here! SBS 2011, and every hour this service starts and freezes the entire server: I can't connect through RDP, users complain because can work with their files in the server... Really annoying... Googling it shows results about something with Trend Micro (which I've installed on the server), but it's up to date :-/